# Querying deeply nested properties run an Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, nested, dql

I am trying to get all the distinct brands from my entity products in a school project using Symfony and Doctrine. After looking for a while I found a answer here and was able to create this function in my ProductRepository.

**ProductRepository Method**

```
public function getDistinct()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('product');
        $res = $query
            ->select ( "product.idProductModel")
            ->distinct(true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $res;
    }
```

However I have two problems. One: I run into an Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression error when i try to do `product.idProductModel` or what i really want `product.idProductModel.idBrand.name` Both idProductModel and idBrand are foreign keys to my Product entity. This query works fine on non nested properties. I am able to get an array of objects of comments if i do for example `product.comment`.
Which bring me to the second problem. I do not want an array of object but instead something that would look like this:

**Format wanted**

```
{
brands: [
    "Agilent",
    "Comtr"
    "Anot
      ],
types:[
     "Accelerometer",
     "Sonometer",
     "Micro-amplifier"
]
}
```

I also have the same problem if i try to do `product.idProductModel.idType.name`.

I am new to programming and would appreciate any help. Thank you.